# Lighting glitching out for grease pencil

Tags: rendering, lighting, grease-pencil

I've made quite a few greasepencil and blender projects, but for some reason on this project the lights (sun in my case) have started being very inconsistent and glitchy.

This also happens in the render, so it's not a viewport bug. I have lights enabled, and area lights work fine.

https://youtu.be/P1PWvQbOO9g this is a partial test render, just so you can see what's going on.

I'll upload the file if needed, i just have a really slow internet connection so i'd rather not.

Comment: hi, i can't really think of anything just with the description and the short clip. Maybe you could delete everything that's not essential from the file and try uploading that?